# The phase of FFT in python and octave does not work properly

Tags: python, numpy, fft, octave, dft

I've been trying to plot the amplitudes and phases of the DFT against the frequency indices in both Octave and Python (Spyder) but the phases seem wrong.

When I do the FFT of a cosine function (the one in the codes) which should have no phase at all for all DFT frequencies, both octave and python plot non-zero frequencies. When I try to extract just the imaginary parts of the FFT  (which are in this case zero) using the imag command for octave and the np.imag command for python instead of the angle commands shown in the codes, I get non-zero imaginary parts as well. However, if I include an initial phase (say pi/3) so that there are exactly two non-zero phases, the angle commands are still yielding the wrong result, but the imag commands seem to work fine. When I change the frequency of my cosine function (for instance from 2pi/16 to 2pi/10) so that the phase is non-zero for nearly off frequencies, both the angle and the imag commands yield the correct results.

Here are the codes I've been using:

Python

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.fft import fft
k = np.linspace(0, 63, 64, endpoint=True)
N = 64
omg = 2.0*np.pi/16
phi= 0
x = 3.0*np.cos(omg*k+phi)
y = fft(x, N,)

plt.figure(1)
plt.stem(k, np.abs(y))
plt.title('Magnitude')
plt.legend()
plt.figure(2)
plt.stem(k, np.angle(y))
plt.title('Phase')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Octave

```
n = [0: 63];
x= 3*cos(2*pi*n/16);
N1= 64;
fft(x, N1)
F=fft(x, N1);

subplot(2, 1, 1)
k= 0:1:N1-1;
stem(k, abs(F));
title('Magnitude');
xlabel('Frequency index'); ylabel('Magnitude');
subplot(2, 1, 2)
k = 0:1:N1-1;
stem(k, angle(F));
title('Phase');
xlabel('Frequency index'); ylabel('Phase');
```

I have virtually zero experience in programming and have no idea what could be wrong here. Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: The FFTs work fine. You are probably getting confused by the non-zero imaginary components when you expect them to be zero. This is an artifact of the FFT computations performed by a digital computer (with finite precision arithmetic). However, note that the values of the expected-to-be-zero imaginary components are of the order of `10^(-15)`, which, for the vast majority of practical purposes, is so small that can be treated as zero.

Comment: @Stelios Thanks a lot for your clarification. I thought it could have something to do with finite precision arithmetic, but I wasn't really sure and didn't want to take any chances. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @Stelios May I have a question here about numpy.fft - have you ever tried to force numpy.fft tool to work with python arbitrary precision numbers as from **`Decimal`** module? I did use it for some L-BFGS solver cases, where it worked excellently together with more than some 200+ decimal places, yet having no such experience from using this strategy for **`numpy.fft`** - would that work together too?

Comment: @user3666197 I never tried it. I wouldn't expect it to work though, since FFT is probably implemented assuming finite precision input and internal computations (so that it runs fast). But you can always give it a shot. Another option is to "manually" compute the FFT (as a function implementing the FFT formula), which can, of course, be made to operate on arbitrary precision numbers (but it would be much slower to compute). But do you really need such a high precision for your application?

Comment: @Stelios thanks for your kind remarks. I thought the same for the L-BFGS ( FORTRAN originated ) **`numpy`** code, which surprised me to indeed work as a charm with the `numpy` non-native `dtype`, as noted above. I.e. I gave it a shot when it was needed in the L-BFGS context, yet was interested, if that might also work for a bit "wilder" case, whether the code capable of processing `Decimal`-s in L-BFGS could similarly extend this capability "beyond" the default `dtype = np.complex128`